# form notification html css

Tags: validation, css, forms

I'm trying to create a form where validation hints appear once the user has focused on an input field. I created this originally for a different website but am having trouble converting it to function within a different website. The form hint lies within the .

I think I've missed something out within the CSS marking, would be grateful if anyone had any ideas.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Here's the HTML

```
    <body>
<div id="container">
<div id="mast-head">
<div id="portal-logo"></div>
<div id="ramsay-logo"></div>
</div>
<div id="nav"><div id="logout"><a href="#">Log Out</a></div><a href="#"><img src="images/home-icon.jpg" width="20" height="20" /></a><span class="breadcrumb">Login</span><span class="breadcrumb">Your Treatment</span>
</div>
<div id="form-content">
    <fieldset>
        <form name="your-treatment" action="" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="email">Proposed operation</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" />
<span class="hint">This is the name your mama called you when you were little.<span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS

```
    .hint {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: -250px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    border: 1px solid #c93;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    /* to fix IE6, I can't just declare a background-color,
    I must do a bg image, too!  So I'm duplicating the pointer.gif
    image, and positioning it so that it doesn't show up
    within the box */
    background: #ffc url(pointer.gif) no-repeat -10px 5px;
}

/* The pointer image is hadded by using another span */
.hint .hint-pointer {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url(pointer.gif) left top no-repeat;
}
```

Here's the Javascript...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      oldonload();
      func();
    }
  }
}

function prepareInputsForHints() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
        // test to see if the hint span exists first
        if (inputs[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]) {
            // the span exists!  on focus, show the hint
            inputs[i].onfocus = function () {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "inline";
            }
            // when the cursor moves away from the field, hide the hint
            inputs[i].onblur = function () {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
    // repeat the same tests as above for selects
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (var k=0; k<selects.length; k++){
        if (selects[k].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]) {
            selects[k].onfocus = function () {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "inline";
            }
            selects[k].onblur = function () {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(prepareInputsForHints);
</script>
```

Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need javascript for this...

What I did to display the hint was affect `.hint`'s properties when the input is `:focus`sed. All you have to do is style it the way you want it to look. [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5A88/)

```
input:focus + .hint {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    left: -10px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url(pointer.gif) left top no-repeat;
}
```

Also if you have multiple inputs you can affect them using a class instead of the generic `input` tag

Heck, you can even animate it using opacity and CSS transition [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5A88/1/) if you wanted to

Comment: Thanks for responding @Zeaklous what you've done in the jsfiddle is exactly what I was attempting however the hint still doesn't appear after it's focused on in the context of the webpage i'm working on. It works fine on the jsfiddle you created but has no effect for me on the webpage

Comment: haha sorry I meant to add it... I've edited my original post so that it now has the entirety of the body HTML in it